# Plone - Syntax Error when doing hello world tutorial

Tags: syntax-error, plone

I am following [this](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/helloworld/index.html) "hello world" tutorial on plone.org

But I stuck in [one moment](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/helloworld/environment/plone.html) due to error:

```
root@junvb:~/Plone/python_dev/env-27# cd hello_world
root@junvb:~/Plone/python_dev/env-27/hello_world# ../bin/python bootstrap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bootstrap.py", line 70, in <module>
exec urllib2.urlopen(setup_url).read() in ez
File "<string>", line 1
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I dumped complete [very very long] console output [here](https://gist.github.com/Logrus/a734f17d95eb75973b49).

What causes this and how to avoid it?

EDIT:

Here the [bootstrap.py](https://gist.github.com/Logrus/6821480593110b0f0b1d)

And also buildout.cfg which in the same folder

```
# This is here just for backward compatibility
[buildout]
extends =
    src/base.cfg
    src/readline.cfg
    src/libjpeg.cfg
    src/python27.cfg
    src/pypy.cfg
    src/pypy3.cfg
    src/links.cfg

parts =
    ${buildout:base-parts}
    ${buildout:readline-parts}
    ${buildout:libjpeg-parts}
    ${buildout:python27-parts}
    ${buildout:pypy-parts}
    ${buildout:pypy3-parts}
    ${buildout:links-parts}

python-buildout-root = ${buildout:directory}/src

# we want our own eggs directory and nothing shared from a
# ~/.buildout/default.cfg to prevent any errors and interference
eggs-directory = eggs

[install-links]
prefix = /opt/local
```

Comment: What does the code looks like at line 70?

Comment: I added the whole file as well.

Comment: It could be that this tutorial is just outdated. Seems like here https://github.com/plone/documentation/issues/232 somebody encountered another problem with the same tutorial and community simply referred to another training materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your bootstrap.py is outdated and tries to access a URL that does not exist any longer. You can update your bootstrap like this:

```
$ rm bootstrap.py
$ wget http://downloads.buildout.org/1/bootstrap.py
$ python2.7 bootstrap.py
$ bin/buildout
```

Comment: It moved further, but there are still errors... http://pastebin.com/yvG6Sq4X  EDIT: Sorry, log can be a bit confusing since I didn't find "instance" script in bin folder and re-run commands. So the log is for second re-run.

Comment: Take a look at Products.Portaltransforms. It happens not often that a download fails. Then there is an empty python package in your downloads. Delete it and restart buildout.